# Get latitude,longitude from php array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

i am using a query loop to get the values of each post location that i get in an array like this:

```
array(2) { ["latitude"]=> string(10) "37.6221869" ["longitude"]=> string(19) "-0.7113418999999794" }
```

So i use:

```
$meta_coords = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mm_location', true );
```

i need to get a proper markup to this like:

(latitude,longitude)

I need to store all this location values in a php variable that i can pass to the google script with all locations, the jquery code of locations must be like:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

So how may i storage all this values and pass them to my jquery script of google maps?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean with "proper mark up"?

Comment: cast it to a float `<?php $lat = (float)$array['latitude']; ?>`

Comment: What you mean by _proper markup to this like:_ I think you might be in a need of `list`

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Having...

```
$array = array("latitude" => "37.6221869", "longitude" => "-0.7113418999999794");
```

You just can parse it to have your desired string:

```
$string = '('.floatval ($array['latitude']).', '.$array['longitude'].')';
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i have edited the question because i missed some things sorry, so if i use your solution, do you know how can i store all the values in a var to passs it to jquery in the format needed?